# How can I trigger a method within a v-if tag (without v-on)?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a template tag with a v-if condition. I want to trigger a method when this condition is true. Something like:

```
<template v-if="condition">
    {{ doit() }} //trigger method
</template>
```

I want to call the doit method when condition is true. How can I do that?

Comment: What does  the method do? Does it produce anything in the DOM?

Comment: @JasonSmith no it updated just a number in the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the method you want to call doesn't do anything to the DOM, I recommend you move it out of the template, probably to a watcher. Like this:

```js
var app = new Vue( {
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    val1: 1,
    val2: 0
  },
  watch : {
    val1: function() {
      this.val2++;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="val1"/>
  <div>Val1 Modification count: {{ val2 }}</div>
</div>
```